# Fix "error: unknown register name ‘r0’ in ‘asm’"

Tags: assembly, arm, rockbox

I'm trying to port some open-source code to a new platform (specifically, gpsp from [this source](https://github.com/notaz/gpsp) to rockbox fuze+ target).

Right now I'm just trying to get it to compile, and I'll work on getting it to run later. After fixing many of the errors and warnings, I'm left with this error:

```
/home/username/rockbox/apps/plugins/rockgba/gpsp/arm/warm.c: In function  ‘warm_cache_op_range’:
/home/username/rockbox/apps/plugins/rockgba/gpsp/arm/warm.c:65:2: error: unknown register name ‘r3’ in ‘asm’
  __asm__("mov  r0, %0 ;"
  ^
/home/username/rockbox/apps/plugins/rockgba/gpsp/arm/warm.c:65:2: error: unknown register name ‘r2’ in ‘asm’
/home/username/rockbox/apps/plugins/rockgba/gpsp/arm/warm.c:65:2: error: unknown register name ‘r1’ in ‘asm’
/home/username/rockbox/apps/plugins/rockgba/gpsp/arm/warm.c:65:2: error: unknown register name ‘r0’ in ‘asm’
```

The relevant code from `warm.c` is:

```
static void sys_cacheflush(void *start, void *end)
{
#ifdef __ARM_EABI__
    /* EABI version */
    int num = __ARM_NR_cacheflush;
    __asm__("mov  r0, %0 ;"
        "mov  r1, %1 ;"
        "mov  r2, #0 ;"
        "mov  r7, %2 ;"
        "swi  0" : : "r" (start), "r" (end), "r" (num)
            : "r0", "r1", "r2", "r3", "r7");
#else                                          //line 63
    /* OABI */                                 //line 64
    __asm__("mov  r0, %0 ;"                    //line 65
        "mov  r1, %1 ;"                        //line 66
        "mov  r2, #0 ;"
        "swi  %2" : : "r" (start), "r" (end), "i" __ARM_NR_cacheflush
            : "r0", "r1", "r2", "r3");
#endif
}
```

I don't have experience with assembly, and definitely not with ARM, so I've got no clue how to make this work.

Is there some header file I need to include? Or some build flag that needs to be set? Is the code needed at all?

Comment: You should add what ARM toolchain you're using and how you're invoking it - that error suggests it's using the host assembler rather than an ARM cross-assembler.

Comment: @Notlikethat Rockbox seems to use the arm-elf-eabi toolchain. However, for the simulator, it uses regular gcc. I'm not sure how it works. Is there a simple grep I can run on the source code that will give me the information?

Comment: Ah, if there's a host-based API simulator like the iOS one (I know nothing about Rockbox), then a project full of both raw and inline assembly is never going to work anyway - best focus on building for the device and running on real hardware.

Comment: @Notlikethat Is cache flushing even needed on a computer? Could I just comment those lines out and run normally in the sim?

Answer (score 2):

That error comes from passing ARM assembly code to an assembler that doesn't understand it. This is usually the result of a misconfigured toolchain/makefile when cross-compiling - invoking `as` rather than `<cross-compiler-prefix>-as`.

However, from the feedback in the comments, in this particular situation you actually have the opposite problem - right toolchain, wrong code. Since the Rockbox UI simulator is [*not* an emulator](http://www.rockbox.org/wiki/UiSimulator), it will only run x86 code (assuming your host is an x86 PC) and you explicitly *don't* want to cross-compile, thus this ARM build will neither work nor be useful - between the inline ARM assembly, the .S files full of ARM code, and the fact that the end result apparently contains a dynamic recompiler which is going to generate ARM code to execute at runtime, if you start hacking out the things that won't build or work on x86 you're not going to be left with much.

Since gpSP apparently has an x86 build too, I imagine you could - rather counterintuitively - try using that for initial bringup on the simulator, then switch to the ARM build on real hardware once the basics are done.